# Is there any way to get Object type from the memory mapped file in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I want to store objects belonging to different classes in a single memory   mapped file. 
While reading from the file is there any approach to know the object type.

Is memory mapped file is used for only single java class?

```
try {    
    RandomAccessFile memoryMappedFile = new RandomAccessFile(file,mode);    
    long fileSize = memoryMappedFile.length();    
    System.out.println("file size " + fileSize);    
    FileChannel fc = memoryMappedFile.getChannel();    
    System.out.println("Chaannel size" + fc.size());    
    MappedByteBuffer outBuffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());    
    List<MemoryMappedFile> list = new ArrayList<MemoryMappedFile>();    
    while(outBuffer.hasRemaining()) {    
        MemoryMappedFile mf = new MemoryMappedFile(outBuffer.getLong(), outBuffer.getInt(), outBuffer.getDouble());        
        list.add(mf);    
    }
    fc.close();
    memoryMappedFile.close();
}
```

Comment: You should provide more details about what you're looking for and what you've done already. Right now there could be hundreds of different answers to "know the object type" depending on what you mean and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for inappropriate question. I added code which I am thinking will give necessary details. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: removed unwanted spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you make a custom method to serialize your objects you can include starting and ending bytes or a certain format to what you write. Then, knowing how it is written, you can make a method to read files of that specific format. This would, of course, require more work than just using the standard Java serialization library though.